# Setting post_id for single.php based on URL without a redirect

Tags: plugin-development, functions, actions, pre-get-posts, id

I'm migrating a Joomla! database to Wordpress and the website has to remain exact regarding URLs. The Joomla site has its posts with .html extensions, and the importer I created maps the Joomla file URL to the Wordpress post_name as such:

joomla-site.com/Title-of-Joomla-Content.html -> Wordpress DB::post_name title-of-joomla-content

I can access right-out-of-the-box the post on the Wordpress install by of course:
wordpress-site.com/Title-of-Joomla-Content

But I need to change how the permalink system responds. I don't want to use a redirect (which shows in headers), so I'm trying to hook in a function that will select the post ID differently if the URL ends with .html.

Since Wordpress only is activated when a file is not found, real .html files are unaffected. So having a blanket check and change function for any .html files isn't a problem.

I've attempted this:

```
function custom_redirect() {
 global $post_id,$wpdb;
 if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],-5) == '.html') {
    $check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name=%s AND post_status = 'publish'",substr(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),0,-5)));
    if ($check > 0) $post_id = $check;
    // Need to set the post ID for the wp_query here.
 }
}

if (!is_admin()) add_action( 'init', 'custom_redirect' );
```

The above code correctly selects the post ID correctly, but I'm not sure what function or hook to use to force the post (single.php) to display it.

I was able to use the following to set the post ID for every archive.php run, but this doesn't affect the single.php file which simply calls the function the_post.

```
function force_ID($query) {
 $query->set('post_id', '96');
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','force_ID');
```

I have a feeling it might be something simple like changing a global instance of $wp_query, but I'm not sure the best way to do this. Using an init hook probably is too high in the order of execution too.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, here is the solution for anyone else wondering how to do something like this:

```
function force_ID($query) {
 global $wpdb;
 if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],-5) == '.html') {
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name=%s AND post_status = 'publish'",substr(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),0,-5)));
    if ($post_id > 0) $query->set('page_id',$post_id);
 }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','force_ID');
```

In examining the wp-includes/query.php file, I noticed that the object accepts page_id to exclusively select an ID. Using post_id worked for archive post loops, but page_id worked for a single post call.